# How to interpret the meaning of "$y$ solves the DE" to have nice properties.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Assume that

- $I$ is an open interval
- $0 \in I$
- $x$ varies in $I$
- $y$ is a differentiable function of $x$.

Now in the context of these assumptions, consider the following problem.

$$x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y$$

To solve, probably the easiest way is via a separation of variables. Thus, the first step would be to rewrite the equation in the form of:

$$\dfrac{1}{y}\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}$$

Thus, it would be useful if the general solution to this new problem were to coincide precisely with the general solution to the old problem.

However, according to the definitions that I've always been taught, the general solution to the new problem is the empty set. That is, it has no solutions. That's because we require that our solutions $y : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be total functions that satisfy the DE for all $x \in I$. But since $0 \in I$, and since the new problem involves raising $x$ to a negative power, no total function $y : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ solves it.

Thus, according to the definitions I've been taught, the general solution to the new problem fails to coincide with the general solution to the old problem.

**Question**. What are the major approaches to generalizing the notion of a "solution" to a DE such that both equations described above have precisely the same general solution? And, where can I learn more about these approaches?

Comment: In this particular case, before I divide by $y$ I would say what if $y$ was identically zero... ah it would solve the DE... the boundary condition and uniqueness theorem hanging around the background.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy, the problem is that (1) has solutions that hit zero somewhere, but not everywhere. So it gets messy.

Comment: I haven't read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra) in detail, but I hope it is somewhat relevant to this problem.

Comment: @Tunonoc, thanks for the link. I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Rigorous separation of variable arguments use local existence and uniqueness, which applies to  systems in vector field form, $w'=F(w)$ for $w$ in an open subset of $R^n$.  In this case, $w = (y,x)$, EUS gives solutions in the form $w(t)=(y(t),x(t))$ and the so-called $dy/dx$ in the equations is something that exists as a consequence of the inverse function theorem applied to the existent-and-unique local solution in small neighborhoods.

Thus, to even start the process (rigorously), problems 1 and 2 both have to be rewritten as "$dy/dx = (\cdots)$" , which when combined with $x' = 1$ (and the chain rule) becomes the equation for $dw/dt$, and logically is a consequence of it.  But this rewriting would erase the difference between the equations, as both of them are $dy/dx = y/x$.  So I don't see that there is a question to answer if the separation argument is laid out carefully.

Comment: (Or let $x=t$ from the beginning.  The same remarks apply. For separation of variables in general one does not want to assume that the equation will be $dy/dx$ and not $dx/dy$, this could change from neighborhood to neighborhood on the solution curves.  It is clearer to think in terms of a parameterization by some other variable, which often is the same as $x$ or $y$.)

Comment: How do we find our new interval $T$ in which $t$ varies?

Comment: The maximal interval is a function of starting point and starting time.  Extend the solution of $dw/dt = F(w)$ with $w(t_0)=w_0$, for given values of $t_0$ and $w_0$, as far forward and backward in time as it will go. This is the only general prescription.  Note, the vector field (the ODE) is treated as fixed data on a given open set, we are not trying to perform some continuation to a larger region, only asking within the stated region, what is the interval of $t$ values attainable on the solution curve through a point.

Comment: I've read your answer a few times, but honestly I don't get how this is supposed to solve the problem. Suppose we write $(y',x')=(y/x,1),$ where $y$ and $x$ are viewed as functions of a variable $t$ which varies in $T$. Well, this only has a solution if there is no $t \in T$ such that $x(t)=0$. But if our original interval $I$ had the property that $0 \in I$, then our new interval $T$ has the property that we can find $t \in T$ such that $x(t)=0$. So the new problem has no solutions, either.

Comment: I think there are two different matters here.  One is whether the two equations are the same, and I think they always are.  Formats to which an existence and uniqueness theorem applies are vector field $(y,x)'=F(x,y)$ or $y'=f(x,y)$, and a line field $A(x,y) dx + B(x,y) dy = 0$.  In all these formulations the two equations are the same, and you need some such format as a starting point to process the equations using calculus, such as passing from $dy/dx$ to $dx/dy$ or separating variables.  The second matter is about extending solutions through $(0,0)$, which depends on what is a "solution".

Comment: I decided to award you the bounty, because the parametrization thing is a good point. But just to let you know, I still don't feel like the problem is "solved."

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer in two parts: first, the family of general solutions is $\{Ax+By=0 \ | \ (A,B)\in\mathbf{R}^2\}$. No matter *how* "correctly/incorrectly" you find these, they are *perfectly* fine solutions according to any definition you can think of and including at $x=0$. Second, you can rewrite your ODE as a first order system - for example this one:
$$
\dot{x} = x \quad\mbox{and}\quad \dot{y} = y .
$$
(Essentially, you parametrize each curve by some arbitrary variable $t$, instead of by $x$ or by $y$.) This is solved trivially by using *the integrating factor* ${\rm e}^{-t}\ne0$ (in both cases), & you obtain $x=x_0 {\rm e}^{-t}$ and $y=y_0 {\rm e}^{-t}$. Clearly, you can rewrite this as $y_0 x - x_0 y = 0$, which is of the same form as the one I gave above. No divisions by zero.

Now - the blurb. To put it simply, your DE stops being a DE at $x=0$: at that point, it just reads $0=y$. (And, lo & behold, *all* solutions actually become zero at $x=0$; in fact, $y=0$ is *equivalent* to $x=0$ for all solutions with $(A,B)\ne(0,0)$.) What you describe, then, is very much related to this fact. Any (other) method that I can think of to solve the DE won't remove this problem. Integrating factor? Well, that's $1/x$, so there. Polar coordinates? Good call, because this yields the trivial-to-solve eq. $\dot{\theta}=0$, but polar coordinates *themselves* suffer at the origin. I think I'll stop here.

Comment: The two opposite sides of a line through zero have nothing to do with each other.  The general solution to the sometimes-ODE-sometimes-not could go to $0$ and out along a different line, or the same process many times, by slowing down the motion near $0$.  This is why it is better talk about solutions only of the thing that is a proper ODE, where the existence and uniqueness of solutions applies.

Comment: I miss a lot of terminology in your comment (&, coincidentally, the point you're trying to make). Terms like `nothing to do w/ each other,' `go [...] along a different line' (when what changes?) & - foremost - `better' (!) bear no intrinsic mathematical meaning. Try again, we might clear it up.

Comment: If you allow solutions $(x(t),y(t))$ that go through values where "the DE stops being a DE" (here it means: going through $0$) then there are solutions that are not confined to one line $Ax+By = 0$, but spend some time on one line, then go to $0$, then move on another line, then return to $0$, etc (with infinitely many different lines, if you like).

Comment: There's no way to pass from one ray to another (let alone infinitely many...) in the formulation I gave; the origin is a fixed point. Also, there's no way to move *away* from zero and then *return* back to it - in this or *any* other time-inveriant formulation as a 1st order system. That would mean that the associated vector field is ill-defined, as it points *both* away from zero and towards it depending on how it suits you :). If something, then the "problem" is that each solution of the 1st order system captures a ray & *not* an entire line. (That's why we have phase portraits, naturally.)

Comment: I think you should state what is a "solution" to the problem in your definition.  Your answer appears to be requiring differentiable functions $x(t),y(t)$ satisfying (1) $xy' - yx'=0$ for all $t$ where $x(t) \neq 0$, and $y(t)=0$ for all $t$ such that $x(t)=0$.  Is that correct?

Comment: If you further require $y$ as a function of $x$ (which is somewhat incompatible with separation of variables, but never mind), is $y = |x|$ a solution?  It passes from one ray to another, satisfies the ODE for positive and negative $x$, and meets the condition that when $x=0$, $y=0$ (which appears to be your interpretation of the  ODE at $x=0$).

Comment: Exactly :) - first thing  first: one *must* decide what constitutes a solution. In my view(s) of the problem, $dy/dx$ is shorthand for a vector field on the plane. I find this a useful generalization of what user18921 had in mind ('$y$ as a differentiable function of $x$') &, since the question is about generalizations, I score a proverbial point. Since I failed (here, I confess) to keep in mind that $y$ *is* supposed to be a differentiable function of $x$, I lose it :). So, ray unions (e.g., $y=|x|$) *are* solutions, even at the origin. [cont'd]

Comment: In the end, all of this is just differential geometry - recall that  a vector on a manifold is given, in that context, as a curve. More on this maybe later. (Btw, I'm greatly enjoying this conversation & I think it positively leads to s'thing; I hope you do too :).)